# How to attach activity in Sherlock Tab?

Tags: android-fragments, actionbarsherlock, android-tabhost, android-tabactivity

I have a activity that will have 3 fragments. I want to add this activity into sherlock Tab. Actually I will have 3 Tabs and each tab will have 3 fragments. 
So I thought to add activity into tab that activity will hold 3 fragments.
In sherlock sample code I found how to attach 1 fragment into tab. But here I am trying to add 3 fragments in each tab. I am doing wrong design. Is there any way to achieve this using Sherlock library?

Comment: If anyone knows please let me know.